# displaying JSON API response in HTML using angular js

Tags: angularjs, json, api

I am new to angular JS.

I am trying to display data from JSON API response  . HTML is not displaying data from the API. Thanks for your help in advance.

Below is the API response.

```
{
"Error": false,
"Message": "Success",
"sensors": [
{
  "SENSOR_ID": 1,
  "SENSOR_NAME": "Hygro meter 1",
  "SENSOR_TYPE": "soil humidity sensor"
},
{
  "SENSOR_ID": 2,
  "SENSOR_NAME": "Hygro meter 2",
  "SENSOR_TYPE": "soil humidity sensor"
},
{
  "SENSOR_ID": 3,
  "SENSOR_NAME": "Hygro meter 3",
  "SENSOR_TYPE": "soil humidity sensor"
}

]
}
```

and below is the HTML part .

Can you please help.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Angular JS Includes</title>
<style>
table, th , td {
border: 1px solid grey;
border-collapse: collapse;
padding: 5px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #ffffff;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
<tr>
<th>Sensor ID</th>
<th>Sensor Name</th>
<th>Sensor Type</th>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
<td>{{ x.SENSOR_ID }}</td>
<td>{{ x.SENSOR_NAME }}</td>
<td>{{ x.SENSOR_TYPE }}</td>

</tr>
</table>
</div>


<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

$http.get("http://54.244.108.186:4000/api/sensors")
.then(function (response)

{$scope.names = response.data.sensors;});

});


</script>

<script    
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js">                
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the JSON response:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af8pP.png)

Comment: `sensors` is a *json* or an *object*?

Comment: try `JSON.parse(response).data.sensors`

Answer (score 1):

**Try this working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
  $scope.names = [
{
  "SENSOR_ID": 1,
  "SENSOR_NAME": "Hygro meter 1",
  "SENSOR_TYPE": "soil humidity sensor"
},
{
  "SENSOR_ID": 2,
  "SENSOR_NAME": "Hygro meter 2",
  "SENSOR_TYPE": "soil humidity sensor"
},
{
  "SENSOR_ID": 3,
  "SENSOR_NAME": "Hygro meter 3",
  "SENSOR_TYPE": "soil humidity sensor"
}
];

$scope.column = Object.keys($scope.names[0]);

});
```

```css
table, th , td {
border: 1px solid grey;
border-collapse: collapse;
padding: 5px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
<tr>
<th ng-repeat="item in column">{{item}}</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
<td ng-repeat="item in column">{{ x[item] }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: is there any way to create a table when we don't know the column names also? I mean making it total dynamic ?

Comment: but still column names is written like- SENSOR_ID, SENSOR_NAME, SENSOR_TYPE. and how to identity that how many columns are there in result json.?Thanks

Comment: No need to keep track of the column number. It will automatically bind any no. of columns. That's y we called it dynamic.

Comment: ok, but what if i don't know the column names like SENSOR_ID and SENSOR_NAME ?  I mean what i will write in <td> { here } </td> ??

Comment: I updated my answer. You have to just add this line. `<td ng-repeat="item in column">{{ x[item] }}</td>`

Comment: @Mogli Please mark it as correct so that it will be useful for others as well.

Comment: I can't mark it as correct, only the user who asked question can mark as correct.

Answer (score -1):

Just check your response to see if needs converting:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Angular JS Includes</title>
<style>
table, th , td {
border: 1px solid grey;
border-collapse: collapse;
padding: 5px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #ffffff;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
<tr>
<th>Sensor ID</th>
<th>Sensor Name</th>
<th>Sensor Type</th>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
<td>{{ x.name }}</td>
<td>{{ x.key }}</td>
<td>{{ x.url }}</td>

</tr>
</table>
</div>

<script    
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js">                
</script>
  
  <script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get("https://api.mixcloud.com/spartacus/party-time/")
  .then(function (response) {
    
      $scope.names = response.data.tags;
    });

});


</script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

By the way you have to move your angular script tag below Angular reference because it needs it to create the app.

Comment: You don't have to convert anything... `$http` does that internally and json by definition is a string. First statement makes no sense

Comment: Yap that's right, just worth checking, and you didn't check the working example either @charlietfl

Comment: Yaser , Thanks for the quick response. Thanks a lot. My API is up and running now. I replaced the API and the tags , but it is still not working.can you help me out

Comment: I couldn't see your API and that's why I used an open one, is your API open?

Comment: Yaser, Its open now , Please check

Comment: I saw the response but since CORS is not enabled I cannot test it with plunker

Comment: Thanks Yaser . Any idea , what I might need to change in the code to get it working. i am Stuck

Comment: Thanks everyone ,solved it....since the webpage and the API are from different source , I faced the issue. Rectified it ,by having both the services running on same server.